Is there any way to make a namespace implement an interface?
Since a TypeScript namespace is just a JavaScript object, is there any way to make sure that it implements a specific type/interface?
E.g. something like:
interface Monoid<T> {
  neutral: () => T;
  combine(x: T, y: T): T;
}

namespace StringMonoid implements Monoid<string> {
  export function neutral() {
    return ``;
  }

  export function combine(x: string, y: string) {
    return x + y;
  }
}

"Just use class/object" is not really an answer for me. I like namespaces quite a bit because they offer a great deal of flexibility. Unlike classes/objects, you can use them to export types, and, thanks to declaration merging, I can declare a data type and a set of functions that work on it with the same name, without having to instantiate objects etc.
Is there any way to do this?

It's not possible. I know it's not what you want to hear but you can use a class/object AND then declare the namespace with the same name after with types.
